# Multi version Api Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns, architecture, versioning

I had design a multi version API architecture, 
Please give me feedback and suggestion about good and bad, or there are better way to achieve this.

[image]

1. version server (MVC4) to route request to correct API interface(WebApi).
2. version will send to server by header, will default to 1.0 if not header found.

First time I design for multi version API architecture, and google does't have much information for this.

Welcome any suggestion, critic, feedback and anything.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many version you will maintain and what the NFR are for older versions.

Your current setup is fine for only a handful of versions pro's and con's:
+ Same NFR for all versions is possible
+ Quick to achieve at first
- Changes to common resources (like the DB) have an impact on all supported versions, so they have to be re-released, tested, ... which can become quite expensive

An other option is to build a chain of adapters, from version 2.2 to 1.0 and from 3.7 to 2.2:
+ Easier to maintain a large set of versions
+ changes only require one new/updated adapter in the chain
- harder to set up at first
- performance drops per adapter that is being used

For the chain of adapters there are several possible scenarios, have them all in one process or have a separate service for each. Again both have pro's and con's.

As usual, it all depends on your situation.